# Is there an R function to compute Appell's F3 function?

Tags: r

I am searching for an implementation of Appell's F3 function in R. 
Does anyone know whether that exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no available implementation of the F3 function in R. The `tolerance` package contains a function for calculating F1, but that's the closest I could find. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tolerance/versions/2.0.0).